# How do I add the Montreal Regular Light Font to my Shopify theme

Tags: fonts, themes, shopify

I have this added to my theme for headings: https://screenshot.click/20-08-innx8-d8dsi.png

But how do I had the regular font. I already have the Montreal-Regular.ttf file uploaded to the assets folder. What is the code I'm suppose to use to make all the text into a paragraph regular text?

When I mimicked the code shown in screenshot with the file type changes to .ttf, it worked but only on some areas of the theme for regular text, is there something else I'm suppose to add into the code?

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to your CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'Montreal Regular';
  src: url('Montreal-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
body,
p {
  font-family: "Montreal Regular";
}
```